# check if input is available on stdin with timeout

Tags: python

I have a python script that publishes messages that are read from stdin onto a message queue in the network. However, if there wasn't any message on the pipe for a specified amount of time I have to send a heartbeat.

So I have to distinguish between 3 cases:

1. There is input on the pipe that can be processed
2. There was no input for some specified amount of time
3. The piping process has been closed and we can gracefully terminate.

Currently, my code looks as follow:

```
import sys
for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    connection.publish(line)
connection.close()
```

However I need to interrupt the for look if there was any timeout. I.e. `sys.stdin` has not delivered any data for some time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I finally came up with

```
import sys
import select


while True:
    try:
        if select.select([sys.stdin,],[],[],2.0)[0]:
            line = sys.stdin.next()
            print "Got:", line
        else:
            print "No data for 2 secs"

    except StopIteration:
        print 'EOF!'
        break
```

Comment: If you're using Python 3, use sys.stdin.readline().

Comment: Also, with python3, stdin.readline() returns '\n' on an empty line, but '' on EOF, so use that to check for EOF instead of a StopIteration exception.

Comment: Does this actually check whether a new *line* is available or just any content?

Comment: @petiepooo I've checked and it doesn't. `sender_with_delay | python3 while_true_print_stdin_readline.py` does not print newlines when the sender is quiet. it prints what the sender sends as it comes.

Comment: There's an error in your logic, then.  See my other post for what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is looking for a portable solution, this is what I came up with
after lots of trial and error.
It requires the `pywin32` pypi package to work on windows

```py
import os, sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import win32api, win32event, win32file, pywintypes
else:
    import select

def stdin_has_content(timeout: float) -> bool:
    assert timeout >= 0
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        try:
            # without this flush, WaitForSingleObject might return early
            win32file.FlushFileBuffers(win32api.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
        except pywintypes.error:         
            pass # this happens if stdin is already closed, but that's ok
        return win32event.WaitForSingleObject(
            win32api.STD_INPUT_HANDLE, int(timeout * 1000)
        ) == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0       
    else:
        rlist, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
        return bool(rlist)
```

Answer (score -1):

A python3 version of the OP's answer without using exception handling:

```
import sys
import select

while True:
  if select.select([sys.stdin,],[],[],2.0)[0]:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line:
      print('Got:', line, end='')
    else:
      print('EOF!')
      break
  else:
    print('No data for 2 secs')
```