# Is it possible to wait for a key release and then consume the remainder of stdin in Python?

Tags: python, linux

My goal is to have a program that waits for a key to be released, and then consumes standard input so that the next program to run in a script does not pick up the input that was emitted by the key being held down.

Currently, I've cobbled together a script based on a combination of these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41521576/391161) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45585167/391161):

#### WaitForRelease.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pynput import keyboard
import sys
import select

def on_key_release(key):
    print('Released Key %s' % key)
    return False


with keyboard.Listener(on_release = on_key_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

while True:
    if select.select([sys.stdin,],[],[],0.5)[0]:
        x = sys.stdin.read()
        print("Got: ", x)
    else:
        break
```

I run it with the following invocation, and then hold down the `f` key for 5 seconds and release. Then I type Control-D to send EOF to `cat`.

```
stty -echo; ./WaitForRelease.py; stty echo; cat
```

#### Expected / Desired output

```
Released key 'f'

Got: ffffffffffffffffffffff
```

#### Observed output:

```
Released Key 'f'

fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

The observed output suggests that `cat` got the extra `f`'s and Python failed to consume it.

**What is happening here and is it possible to modify this program (or its invocation) to consume any remaining input from the key press and exit?**

As an extra twist, I am trying to make this work with keys that are held down *before* the program started.

Comment: The keyboard you are listening to is not your standard input. It is the one used by your windowing system. The stream of key presses and releases you get on the keyboard listener is completely separate from what you get on your stdin.

Comment: Why would you even _want_ to do this? Could you describe the context? There might be a simpler way to solve this if we know more of what is going on. (I also agree with @n. m. could be an AI).

Comment: @5rod, I'm trying to implement a piano keyboard on my real keyboard by using `sox` on the command line. As long as a key is depressed, I want sox to keep playing. When the key is released, I want to kill the sox process.

Yes, I know this is hacky, but it's a personal project and I thought it would fun to try without writing real code against libsox. :P

Comment: standard input doesn't encode key releases.  Indeed, standard input doesn't know about  keys.  Your standard input can come from a file, and then there are not keys pressed or released.  That info died along in the path from the computer to your program.

Comment: You also never send `EOF` to the program.  Pressing Ctrl-D will make the program to send nothing to the prorgram.  Exactly as when you end reading a file, you get nothing from the `read(2)` system call.

Comment: I realize that standard input does not know about keys, but I also know that while a key is pushed down, it continuously generates input to `stdin`.
That's why I'm using the timeout to determine when there's nothing more in stdin.